# Drawing two objects that need to collide and have different behaviors

Tags: android, opengl-es, collision-detection, behavior

I want to create a scene that has one square that bounces around the screen and one that stays on the spot (rotating possibly). The collision detection should be easy in this case but should I initialise the squares completely separate (in two different classes) or should I assign behaviour in the draw method?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Well both the squares are the same so there should be a Square class that makes the squares and then it may be best to create a CollisionDetection class. This class can be used to test of the squares have overlapped each other (collided) and it will return either true or false.

```
public static boolean SquareCollision(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2) {
    if(r1.lowerLeft.x < r2.lowerLeft.x + r2.width &&
       r1.lowerLeft.x + r1.width > r2.lowerLeft.x &&
       r1.lowerLeft.y < r2.lowerLeft.y + r2.height &&
       r1.lowerLeft.y + r1.height > r2.lowerLeft.y)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Hey while we're on the subject I'm trying this example you gave me. I try to draw 2 squares from the same class with different names (square and statsquare) why does my app crash with a NullPointerException? Are you meant to draw squares from the same class differently?

Comment: You wont be creating the squares in memory, you need to do Square square = new Square(); and Square statsquare = new Square();

Comment: Can I ask why you always use the lowerleft corner in your maths? and not top left and lower right ect.

Comment: sorry about extra questions, but is Rectangle the class used to initialize the square? and are width, height, x, y and lowerLeft meant to be defined in the Rectangle class? Do you share the variables of square and statsquare with this class by defining as public static in the renderer class? Again thanks for the help =D

Comment: The Rectangle is my own class, you could use Rect which is a java class but it has a lot of fancy things that you wont use. I just use the bottom left because on OpenGL the bottom left of the screen is define as 0,0,0 (or at least thats how I do it.) The collision check class is static so it doesnt need to define the squares, as long as you pass it into the method it will be fine. Esentailly you want a class that is used for harnessing everything in your game, one for rendering and one that contains the level data (such as positions, what actually in the level and where.)

Comment: public Rectangle(float x, float y, float width, float height) {
        this.lowerLeft = new Vector2(x,y);
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }  This is my Rectangle Class...also Vector2 is something of mine but it just tracks an X and Y coordinate

Comment: Oh and the reason a Rectangle is passed in is because in my code I do something like theSprite.bounds and the "bounds" is defined as a Rectangle. The bounds is used to manually define the collision area of that object, in most cases the width and height of the object is sufficient but at least this way I can tweak certain things